# Need proper directory structure for python packages and guidelines on good API design

Tags: python, import, pip, pypi, module-packaging

I am in the midst of releasing a python package, and am confused about every aspect of packaging.

To start, my directory structure is as follows:

```
SamplePackage/
 - setup.py
 - README.rst
 - LICENSE.rst
 - sampledir/
    -__init__.py
    -sample.py
    -utils.py
```

currently `__init__` and `setup` are unpopulated. `sample.py` is the file that any user of the package would want to import. It contains the api in the form of different functions: `foo1`, `foo2`.

`utils.py` contains helper fictions for `smaple.py`. The latter contains a statement `import utils`

Any scripts placed under the `sampledir` directory can easily `import sample`and use the fictions as `sample.foo1()`. Stepping out of this directory, I can call `import sampledir`, but not `import sample`, which is expected. So I need to do `from sampledir import sample`. This results in an error on the `import utils` line in `sample.py`

```
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

In some places I have seen `import .utils` for files in the same directory. But when I try that, it results in a syntax error.

Why can I not import `sample.py` from outside sampledir?

Also, what directory structure would allow users who have installed the package to simply be able to call `import sample` followed by `sample.foo1()`, and not have to do `from sampledir import sample` or `import sampeldir.sample`. For example, in using the HTTP library `requests`, one simply has to import it and call `requests.get(url)`. `requests.requests.get('url')` is not required, like it is in `urllib`. What is the correct directory naming and arrangement to achieve that, if I want the package to be named `sample`?

Comment: If you want it to be like `requests`, [go and look at `requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I thing you've misunderstood what is difference between package and project. You directory structure should be something like this

```
arbitrary_name_of_project/
 - setup.py
 - README.rst
 - LICENSE.rst
 - package_name/
    -__init__.py
    -sample.py
    -utils.py
```

Python package is "marked" by a presence of file `__init__.py`. Python search on his `PYTHONPATH` and seeks for all directories with file `__init__.py` (simply put, it's actually much more complicated). Those are packages that you can import during run-time.

In our case, only `package_name` directory will be installed somewhere to `PYTHONPATH`. Therefore, once installed (via `setup.py` and `disutils` or `setuptools`), you can type

```
import package_name
```

Now, you can call arbitrary class or function or whatever from any module in this package like

```
package_name.sample.func1()
```

If you want to avoid typing `package_name.sample` in you call, you can place this line in `__init__.py`

```
from .sample import func1
```

The function `func1` will be then put in your global name space during "import time". This happens when `import package_name` is executed in your program. This mystery can be resolved by the fact that `__init__.py` file are executed every time package is imported.

It is sometimes necessary to spit the structure even more. You can have "nested" packages (i.e. packages in package that you need to import). There are also namespace packages, where you can "spit" one package among more directories. The world is diverse. :)

**Disclaimer**

I wrote that without testing the code I provided. There might be small typos but I hope the story is more or less correct. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.